# Where do Asp.Net claims holds?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core

As far as i know when we're using default claims based authorization claims are included in token which generated and put it encoded into cookies once we log in. And when we use [Authorize] attribute it just decoded token and check user roles.
But does the same works also for using token from mobile device while using asp.net core web.api? Could someone share link where in details described how claim-based authorization works under the hood?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Claims are effectively stored in-memory, at least in the context of what you're asking about. Regardless of the means of authentication, the end result is a `ClaimsPrincipal` instance in memory, which contains all the claims on it. Things like the `[Authorize]` attribute aren't reading cookies; they're merely accessing `HttpContext.User` (the `ClaimsPrincipal`) which is injected via the framework, through the authentication middleware.